# Interface implementation hiding in OOPS

Tags: c#, oop

What is Interface implementation hiding in OOPS? What are the advantages?

Please can you help me by showing how to hide an interface implementation in C#?

Comment: Can you please refine your question. It's not really clear about what you want to understand concerning Interface and Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: Do you mean hiding the implementation behind an interface for DI etc.? That's one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. You can probably find examples with any of the common C# DI frameworks e.g. ninject.

Comment: I am sure you don't need DI frameworks just to show how to hide the implementation and make the client class rely on an interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implicit and Explicit implementation of interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756520/implicit-and-explicit-implementation-of-interface)

Comment: @Wiktor no, but you'll find good explanations [in their documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand)

Answer (score 5):

Hiding implementation behind an interface = make your client class rely on an interface rather than implementation, i.e.:

```
class A {
   // make use of B somehow
   void Foo( B b )
}

class B { }
```

becomes

```
interface IB { }

class A {
   // hide the implementation behind an interface
   void Foo( IB b ) { }
}

class B : IB { }
```

The advantage of hiding the implementation is that you can change between different implementations and the client code doesn't change.